# FileMaker 9 & PHP API - Total record count?

Tags: php, pagination, filemaker

The only way I can see to get a total record count necessary for setting up some sort of pagination mechanism would be something like:

```
$fileMakerObj = new FileMaker( /* credentials redacted */ );  
$fc = $FileMakerObj->newFindCommand('someLayout');  

//Get max Record count for someLayout 
$fc->setRange(0,0);  
$result1 = $fc->execute();  
$maxRecords = $result1->getTableTotalCount();  
$fc->clearRange();  

//Window 0-100 of $maxRecords  
$fc->setRange(0,100);  
$page1 = $fc->execute();  
//Repeat as necessary
```

Is there something I am missing, or is this the only solution?

Comment: What are you trying to count? Records in a table or a found set?

Comment: Most likely the found set.  I ended up going with the original solution, but curious if there is a better way then scanning through the set to get the total count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One minor but important change:

if you set

```
$fc->setRange(0,0);
```

to get the RecordCount, you actually don's set a range and scan through the set. If you use

```
$fc->setRange(0,1);
```

instead, you only read one record. Then use

```
$result1->getTableRecordCount();
```

to get the record count in the unterlaying table or

```
$result1->getFoundSetCount();
```

for the count of the filtered records.

Comment: Not exactly an answer but it does improve on getting row counts, re-marking yours as correct answer.